# Configuring JVM for GeoServer 10 in Centos?

Tags: geoserver, jvm

I am configuring my freshly installed Geoserver 2.10 based on the [Geoserver docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html).
According to the above URL I need to increase the default heap memory by configuring not my Tomcat container but the JVM (so it applies for all types of containers).

I do that with the following command:

```
 export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms128m -Xmx756M"
```

Then I check it was applied with this command:

```
 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize'
```

But I have noticed the following: Before I set the above parameters, I checked what where the once existing and I got this:

```
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 261347392                    
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4181721088
```

After assigning the new parameters I have this:

```
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 134217728
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 792723456
```

Which are actually much smaller than the initial ones. So should I keep the values from before (how did this values were assigned? Are they based on my system's capabilities?) or I should go with what Geoserver docs recommend even though it is less memory?